# Eigen Dense Storage Segmentation Fault in Open3D function

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, eigen, open3d

I need to do some operation on PointCloud by using Open3D library but it gives me Segmentation Fault and debuggers don't give much information about the problem. It's weird beacause the same code works on Windows but on Ubuntu gives such an error.

GDB backtrace output:

```
#0  0x00005555555f5c77 in open3d::geometry::Geometry3D::ComputeMinBound(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> > > const&) const (this=0x7fffffffd250, points=...) at /home/rufus/Open3D/cpp/open3d/geometry/Geometry3D.cpp:50
#1  0x000055555561d951 in open3d::geometry::PointCloud::GetMinBound() const (this=<optimized out>) at /home/rufus/Open3D/cpp/open3d/geometry/PointCloud.cpp:52
#2  0x0000555555622dcd in open3d::geometry::PointCloud::VoxelDownSample(double) const (this=0x7fffffffd250, voxel_size=0.01) at /home/rufus/Open3D/cpp/open3d/geometry/PointCloud.cpp:312
#3  0x000055555557a690 in colorCloudRegistrationOptimization(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> const>, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> const>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4> const&) ()
#4  0x000055555557d569 in main ()
```

Valgrind output:

```
==7030== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7030==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==7030==    at 0x1A9C47: DenseStorage (DenseStorage.h:194)
==7030==    by 0x1A9C47: PlainObjectBase (PlainObjectBase.h:520)
==7030==    by 0x1A9C47: Matrix (Matrix.h:413)
==7030==    by 0x1A9C47: open3d::geometry::Geometry3D::ComputeMinBound(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> > > const&) const (Geometry3D.cpp:50)
==7030==    by 0x1D1920: open3d::geometry::PointCloud::GetMinBound() const (PointCloud.cpp:52)
==7030==    by 0x1D6D9C: open3d::geometry::PointCloud::VoxelDownSample(double) const (PointCloud.cpp:312)
==7030==    by 0x12E68F: colorCloudRegistrationOptimization(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> const>, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> const>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4> const&) (in /home/rufus/HoloportationLinuxPart/san_holo/build/san_holo
```

I tried to compile it with EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As the address reported by Valgrind is so low 0x10, it let me think you are using a NULL pointer to an object or an uninitialized object.